# Getting domain expiration date /registration date via curl and preg_match issue

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am trying to get expiration date / registration date of a domain but I end up with a really unexpected result, I get 3 elements in the array with same value.

```
$domain = trim($domain); // ex google.com
$url = "http://who.is/whois/".$domain;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = trim($result);
$result = preg_match('/(<span data-bind-domain="expiration_date" style="visibility: visible;">(.*?)<\/span>){1}/', $result, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

// output

```
array(3) { 
     [0]=> string(95) "September 14, 2020" 
     [1]=> string(95) "September 14, 2020" 
     [2]=> string(18) "September 14, 2020" 
}
```

I am trying to get and stock into a variable the expiration date and into another variable the registration date + first 2 arrays are sending 95 chars of string when there are only 18.

What am I mistaking

ADDED

```
$result = preg_match('#<td><span data-bind-domain="expiration_date" style="visibility: visible;">(.*?)</span></td>#', $result, $matches);
```

instead of

```
$result = preg_match('/(<span data-bind-domain="expiration_date" style="visibility: visible;">(.*?)<\/span>){1}/', $result, $matches);
```

and now is outputting very odd, without saying what type of variable it is, the first date.
September 14, 2020, doesn't say if it is string or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
        http://www.nott.org/blog/php-whois-script.html

Some registrars offers API, which will make your job easier : http://opensrs.com/site/integration/api

Comment: In order to use their api, you need to become a reseller and that costs about 100 USD. I am really amazed that no one can fix this issue from my code, I got everything fixed here on SO.

Comment: Try http://whois.net/whois/www.sitename.com
that who.is is not working for me

Or you can use bash scripts to do the job.